# Add buildCommand in .project with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I need to use Maven to add a new *buildCommand* in my `.project` file.

My `.project` file (it was created by Maven):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>myProject</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
</projects>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Nature</nature>
</natures>
```

I have to add the following *buildCommand*:

```
<buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
        <triggers>auto,full,incremental,</triggers>
        <arguments>
            <dictionary>
                <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
                <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/myLuncher.launch</value>
            </dictionary>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Someone has any idea how I can do this?

Comment: What's wrong with inserting your new `buildCommand` after the `maven2Builder` one?

Comment: This project and distributed and .project is not in the repository, It is automatically generated by maven on each computer. If I manually add the new commandBuilder, the change will be only reflected on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524031/281545) Attila - with some minor modifications I made it work. I tried to edit your post, but the edit was not accepted...

I used the plugin in the following way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildCommand>
                <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
                <triggers>auto,full,incremental,</triggers>
                <arguments>
                    <LaunchConfigHandle>
                    &lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/myLuncher.launch
                    </LaunchConfigHandle>
                </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
        </additionalBuildcommands>  
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I use the version 2.7 and not 2.9 because it allowed me to use the command `eclipse:m2eclipse` and then to use the Project with m2eclipse Plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can update your maven pom.xml file based on the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/provide-project-natures-and-build-commands.html):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    <additionalBuildcommands>
      <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
      <triggers>auto,full,incremental,</triggers>
      <arguments>
        <dictionary>     
          <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>     
          <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/myLuncher.launch</value>
        </dictionary>
      </arguments>
    </additionalBuildcommands>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, when you call `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it will re-generate the .project file with your added `buildCommand`